# During high load MQQueueConnectionFactory suddenly change port to default port 1414

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

During high load, we see that the MQQueueConnectionFactory suddenly trying to connect to default MQ port 1414 instead of the assigned port.

**Background:** 
We use Websphere 9.0.5.13 to deploy an ear file. Java version: 8.0.7.15.
The server in this Websphere communicate to external IBM MQ. We use IBM MQ library version: com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.5.0.jar.
We connect to 3 different IBM MQ queue managers and hundreds of channels. We don't use IBM MQ default port numbers i.e. 1414. Instead, we override it to some other ports.
We always use new MQQueueConnectionFactory before we send to a queue, and close the sender, session, and connection afterwards.

**Issue:**
At the start of server, we process multiple queues simultaneously. Most of the time, this causes:

> JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').

Digging deeper, it is because the MQQueueConnectionFactory try to connect to default port 1414 instead of the correct port we have configured.

> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'ecpmq2(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'hostname******/ipaddr***.***.***.***:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[A remote host did not respond within the timeout period. (Connection timed out)],3=hostname******/ipaddr***.***.***.***:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=hostname******(1414),4=,5=RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket]

I tried to replicate the scenario in local PC and our test env, but to no avail.

**Sample Code:**
This is the code that we have. Yes, the code is farcry from being efficient, but it still does not explain why suddenly the MQ try to connect to default port.

```
        for (String msg : messages) {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = null;
            MQQueueConnection mqConn = null;
            try {
                queueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
                queueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueInfo.getQueueManager());
                queueConnectionFactory.setHostName(queueInfo.getHostname());
                queueConnectionFactory.setPort(queueInfo.getPort());
                queueConnectionFactory.setChannel(queueInfo.getChannel());
                queueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
                
                mqConn = (MQQueueConnection) queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
                mqConn.start();
                sendSingleMsg(mqConn, queueInfo.getQueueName(), msg);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                printQueueDetails(queueConnectionFactory);
            } finally {
                if (mqConn != null) {
                    try {
                        mqConn.close();
                    } catch (JMSException ex) {
                        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    }
                    mqConn = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Question:**
Is it possible that MQQueueConnectionFactory fail somewhere due to high concurrency and set the port to default port instead of the assigned port? Does it keep some failover set of hostnames and it includes the default port?

Comment: Honestly the fact that you are creating a new MQQueueConnectionFactory everytime will cause problems anyways.  Maybe there is a failover happening where it switches to another instance.   Look into your broker and how it is configured on the backend side, not from your code.

Comment: @JCompetence, thanks. I will check at configuration and logs of the IBM MQ. Any suggestions on which settings I should be looking at? Sorry, I'm new to this IBM MQ setting as it is handled by different team.

Comment: If you are on WAS, why you set up QCF in your code? You should configure that externally in the WAS server and then just inject/lookup via JNDI. Then you are utilizing WAS connection pooling instead of recreating everything each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this item.
I put logging in various place to log the port number. Then we found out that the port in `queueConnectionFactory` was intermittently reset to default port after calling `queueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);`

After updating the log level of ibm mq to TRACE, I found that new MQ library `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.5.0.jar` has a `portSet` flag that would be set via a thread in somewhere in `setPort()`. Since it is set using a thread, and not via a sequential method call, there is a chance the thread does not start or start later than the current thread that will call `queueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);`. If that happens, the port would be reset to default value.
This is the snippet of what happen deep inside `setPort()`

```
if (parent instanceof MQConnectionFactory) {
                AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
                    public Object run() {
                        if (Trace.isOn) {
                            Trace.entry(this, "com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQPortPropertyValidator", "run()");
                        }

                        try {
                            Field portSetField = MQConnectionFactory.class.getDeclaredField("portSet");
                            portSetField.setAccessible(true);
                            portSetField.setBoolean(parent, true);
```

and this is the snippet of what happen inside `queueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);`

```
if (!this.portSet) {
  this.setPort(1414);
  this.portSet = false;
}
```

**The fix** is VERY SIMPLE! Just need to call `setTransportType` before calling `setPort`

```
queueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
// call setTransportType first
queueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
queueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueInfo.getQueueManager());
queueConnectionFactory.setHostName(queueInfo.getHostname());
queueConnectionFactory.setChannel(queueInfo.getChannel());
// call setPort last
queueConnectionFactory.setPort(queueInfo.getPort());
mqConn = (MQQueueConnection) queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
```

Comment: Did you open a case to let IBM know about this behavior?   I'm sure they would consider this a defect.

Comment: I didn't since problem already solved. I suppose we should to help others, but later.. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One reason may be down to not testing what

```java
queueInfo.getPort()
```

returns. I would log the return, to see if there are conditions when it doesn't return the port you are expecting.

Comment: see the solution the OP posted,  seems like a defect,  maybe you can get it on front of the right people (paul t?)

Comment: I'll ask around.

Comment: @fauzimh This does look like a defect. Are you able to raise a service request for it?